# How to iterate over XPATH using only even index in a FOR loop

Tags: python, selenium, loops, for-loop, xpath

This is a snippet of my code

```
alternative_solutions = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "flight-row")
                positive("Total number of Alternative options found are {}".format(len(alternative_solutions)))

k = 1
for j in range(2, len(alternative_solutions),2):
   flight_number = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//hgb-alternative-flights[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tr[{}]/td[2]" .format(j)))).text
```

I am trying to iterate over a table and capture the values using the for loop. The table in question has 10 solutions (lets suppose). Each of the solution I can iterate over the XPATH.

The problem here is that the solutions are only available on the even number i.e I can iterate over only 2,4,6 and so on.

With the for loop that I have, I am able to iterate 4 times and then the loop exits.

How do I handle this gracefully

The HTML looks like where ng-star-inserted is only for spacing

```
<table _ngcontent-vxq-c254 xpath="1"> == $0
    <tr _ngcontent-vxq-c254 class="ng-star-inserted">..</tr>
    <!---->
    <tr _ngcontent-vxq-c254 class="flight-row ng-star-inserted">..</tr>
    <!---->
    <tr _ngcontent-vxq-c254 class="ng-star-inserted">..</tr>
    <!---->
    <tr _ngcontent-vxq-c254 class="flight-row ng-star-inserted">..</tr>
    <!---->
</table>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use the `flight-row` directly in the xpath expression?  Then you wouldn't need to wory about iterating every other element, you can just iterate the results directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe

```
for j in range(2, len(alternative_solutions) + 2, 2):
    ...
```

As you remember,range() includes the start value but excluding the end one

Answer (score 0):

Consider making the XPath expression more selective:

```
(/my/path/expression)[position() mod 2 = 0]
```